# Java Process Builder - Cannot run a simple program

Tags: java, processbuilder, darknet

I have a program called `darknet`. It's a C-program made from [Darknet](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/).

I want to run the `darknet` program in a folder `Darknet` that looks like this:

[image]

I'm going to run `darknet` with Java Process Builder, but I get no responce from it when I run this code:

```
    // Arguments
    String darknetNamePath = darknet.getValue().getFilePath().replace("Darknet/", "./");
    String configurationFlag = configuration.getValue().getFilePath().replace("Darknet/", "");
    String weightsFlag = weights.getValue().getFilePath().replace("Darknet/", "");
    String imageFlag = "data/cameraSnap.png";
    String thresholdFlag = "-thresh " + thresholds.getValue();
    
    // Process builder
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    processBuilder.directory(new File("Darknet")); // We need to stand inside the folder "Darknet"
    String commandString = "detect " + configurationFlag + " " + weightsFlag + " " + imageFlag + " " + thresholdFlag;
    System.out.println("darknetNamePath  = " + darknetNamePath);
    System.out.println("commandString  = " + commandString);
    processBuilder.command(darknetNamePath, commandString);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);
```

Here is my output. Why doesn't it work for me?

```
darknetNamePath  = ./darknet
commandString  = detect cfg/yolov2-tiny.cfg weights/yolov2-tiny.weights data/cameraSnap.png -thresh 0.8

Exited with error code : 0
```

But when I call `darknet` file via terminal, then it works.

```
./darknet detect cfg/yolov2-tiny.cfg weights/yolov2-tiny.weights data/cameraSnap.png -thresh 0.6
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is my update.

```
    // Arguments
    String darknetNamePath = darknet.getValue().getFile().getAbsolutePath();
    String configurationFlag = configuration.getValue().getFilePath().replace("Darknet/", "");
    String weightsFlag = weights.getValue().getFilePath().replace("Darknet/", "");
    String imageFlag = "data/cameraSnap.png";
    String thresholdFlag = "-thresh " + thresholds.getValue();

    // Process builder
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    processBuilder.command(darknetNamePath, "detect", configurationFlag, weightsFlag, imageFlag, thresholdFlag);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    if (process.getInputStream().read() == -1) {
        System.out.println(darknetNamePath);
        System.out.println("detect");
        System.out.println(configurationFlag);
        System.out.println(weightsFlag);
        System.out.println(imageFlag);
        System.out.println(thresholdFlag);
        System.out.printf("ERROR!");
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);
```

Output:

```
/home/dell/Dokument/GitHub/Vaadin-DL4J-YOLO-Camera-Mail-Reporter/Vaadin-DL4J-YOLO-Camera-Mail-Reporter/Darknet/darknet
detect
cfg/yolov2-tiny.cfg
weights/yolov2-tiny.weights
data/cameraSnap.png
-thresh 0.3
ERROR!
Exited with error code : 0
```

**UPDATE 3:**

This works:

```
            // Arguments
            String darkPath = darknet.getValue().getFilePath().replace("Darknet/", "./"); // We need to call ./darknet, not absolute path
            String configurationFlag = configuration.getValue().getFilePath().replace("Darknet/", "");
            String weightsFlag = weights.getValue().getFilePath().replace("Darknet/", "");
            String imageFlag = "data/camera.png";
            String thresValue = String.valueOf(thresholds.getValue());

            // Process builder
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
            processBuilder.directory(new File("Darknet")); // Important
            processBuilder.command(darkPath, "detect", configurationFlag, weightsFlag, imageFlag, "-thresh", thresValue);
            processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true); // Important
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command must break all arguments into separate pieces - including `thresholdFlag`. It is a good idea to check if the executable exists. If it does not you should check where it is located or fix your Path variable to ensure that it can be located:

```
File darkpath = new File(darknetNamePath);
String [] cmd = new String[] { darkpath.getAbsolutePath(), "detect", configurationFlag, weightsFlag, imageFlag, "-thresh", String.valueOf(thresholds.getValue()) };

System.out.println("Path: "+darkpath+ " exists="+darkpath.exists());
System.out.println("exec "+Arrays.toString(cmd));

processBuilder.command(cmd);
```

It is also worth handling STDERR, the easiest way is to redirect STDERR=>STDOUT before calling `processBuilder.start()`

```
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

If you want Java to launch the executable without prefixing the absolute path it needs to be in one of these directories:

```
System.out.println("PATH COMPONENTS FOR JAVA LAUNCH:");
Arrays.asList(System.getenv("PATH").split(File.pathSeparator)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This -> `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);` made so I can at least call the program. Still trouble with the arguments :) Will give you an update soon.

Comment: Good call on capturing stderr as well. Maybe the called program exits with 0 even in case of errors, and without seeing stderr, this is hard to catch,

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ProcessBuilder` the wrong way. The [command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#command(java.lang.String...)) method takes a executable and arguments as separate strings, not a path and then another string with the actual command and all its arguments. There is no shell involved to do word splitting on the command, so you pass all your distinct arguments as one argument.

I don't have darknet, so here's a simple command using the Unix `echo` command:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ProcessBuilderTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        String[] command = {"/bin/echo", "hello", "world"};
        processBuilder.command(command);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with error code : " + exitCode);
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
robert@saaz:~$ java ProcessBuilderTest.java
hello world
Exited with error code : 0
```

It's not clear to my why your command doesn't produce an error. If I give a bad command (e.g., a trailing space behind "echo"), I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/echo ": error=2, No such file or directory
```

This may be OS specific. Or maybe you have some other `darknet` executable that gets picked up.

Comment: Yes! That works. So Process Builder is ONLY for "bash" commands?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with bash or any other shell. ProcessBuilder is for any command, you just have to pass what the `command` method expects.

Comment: So if I pass the full absolute path to the `darknet` file, it still don't work for me. `/home/dell/Dokument/GitHub/Vaadin-DL4J-YOLO-Camera-Mail-Reporter/Vaadin-DL4J-YOLO-Camera-Mail-Reporter/Darknet/darknet`

Comment: Do I have to add something more?

Comment: The key point is that you put the command (plus its path) in one string, and each of the arguments in its own string. Do not use `+` to combine arguments. See the Javadoc I've linked to and my `echo` example. If `darknet` is not in your path, use the full path to the binary.

Comment: I tried what you describe. Did not work. See the update in my question.